# Average Conversion of crystal to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have crystal Formula is

"Weighted Average ({command.Udf_flot5}, {command.total_mkt_val})"

How can i convert this crystal to SSRS expression?

I'm trying to convert crystal to SSRS

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Crystal Reports takes the first argument values and creates the weighted average over the second argument. Something like:

```
=SUM(Fields!Udf_flot5.Value * Fields!total_mkt_val.Value) / SUM(Fields!total_mkt_val.Value)
```